# Access violation from vkCreateGraphicsPipelines

Tags: c++, pipeline, vulkan, access-violation

I'm running into an access violation on this piece of Vulkan API.

```
VkResult err = vkCreateGraphicsPipelines(device, pipelineCache, 1, &pipelineCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipelines.billboard);
```

The error is:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFB8BEDB276 (amdvlk64.dll) in 3Dfunctionvisualizer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000004C.
```

All other relevant code, as far as I can tell:

```
VkPipelineCacheCreateInfo pipelineCacheCreateInfo = {};
pipelineCacheCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_CACHE_CREATE_INFO;
VkResult err = vkCreatePipelineCache(device, &pipelineCacheCreateInfo, nullptr, &pipelineCache);

VkPipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo inputAssemblyState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineInputAssemblyStateCreateInfo(
            VK_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINT_LIST,
            0,
            VK_FALSE);

    VkPipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo rasterizationState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineRasterizationStateCreateInfo(
            VK_POLYGON_MODE_FILL,
            VK_CULL_MODE_BACK_BIT,
            VK_FRONT_FACE_CLOCKWISE,
            0);

    VkPipelineColorBlendAttachmentState blendAttachmentState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineColorBlendAttachmentState(
            0xf,
            VK_FALSE);

    VkPipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo colorBlendState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineColorBlendStateCreateInfo(
            1,
            &blendAttachmentState);

    VkPipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo depthStencilState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineDepthStencilStateCreateInfo(
            VK_TRUE,
            VK_TRUE,
            VK_COMPARE_OP_LESS_OR_EQUAL);

    VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineViewportStateCreateInfo(1, 1, 0);

    VkPipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo multisampleState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineMultisampleStateCreateInfo(
            VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
            0);

    std::vector<VkDynamicState> dynamicStateEnables = {
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT,
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR,
        VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_LINE_WIDTH
    };
    VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo dynamicState =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo(
            dynamicStateEnables.data(),
            dynamicStateEnables.size(),
            0);

    std::array<VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo, 3> shaderStages;

    shaderStages[0] = loadShader("./../data/shaders/3DVisualizer/billboard.vert.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT);
    shaderStages[1] = loadShader("./../data/shaders/3DVisualizer/billboard.geom.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_GEOMETRY_BIT);
    shaderStages[2] = loadShader("./../data/shaders/3DVisualizer/billboard.frag.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);

    VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo pipelineCreateInfo =
        vkTools::initializers::pipelineCreateInfo(
            pipelineLayout,
            renderPass,
            0);

    pipelineCreateInfo.pVertexInputState = &vertices.billboard.inputState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pInputAssemblyState = &inputAssemblyState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pRasterizationState = &rasterizationState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pColorBlendState = &colorBlendState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pMultisampleState = &multisampleState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pViewportState = &viewportState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pDepthStencilState = &depthStencilState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pDynamicState = &dynamicState;
    pipelineCreateInfo.stageCount = 3;
    pipelineCreateInfo.pStages = shaderStages.data();
    pipelineCreateInfo.renderPass = renderPass;
```

The device and pipelineCache are both set by the superclass, which was written by Sascha Willems and works for all of the examples he has created, so I don't expect the problem would be there. However, that really only leaves pipelineCreateInfo or pipelines.billboard as the potential source of the error.

Both of those are dealt with in the (almost exact) same way as the examples by Sascha in his examples, so I'm at a loss here.

EDIT: I found the problem. I had failed to specify the binding point for the sampler in my shader.

Comment: If you've fixed your issue, please answer your own question instead of editing the answer into the question. Also consider using a debug layer (ex. the one from LunarG).

Comment: The best way of dealing with such issues is trying to catch the error with Validation Layers in SDK. This may, of course, propagate the crash to the layer library, but these are open source - making them much easier to debug.